# How to convert columns of numpy arrays to lists when using .to_dict

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to take my pandas Dataframe and convert it to a list of dictionaries. I can do this using the pandas `to_dict('records')` function. However, this function takes any column values that are lists and returns numpy arrays. I would like for the content of the returned list of dictionaries to be base python objects rather than numpy arrays.

I understand I could iterate my outputted dictionaries but I was wondering if there is something more clever to do this.

Here is some sample code that shows my problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = pd.concat([
    pd.Series(['a--b', 'c--d', 'e--f'], name='key'),
    pd.Series(['123', '456', '789'], name='code'),
    pd.Series([np.array(['123', '098']), np.array(['000', '999']), np.array(['789', '432'])], name='codes')
    ], axis=1)

output = data.to_dict('records')

# this prints <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(output[0]['codes']))
```

`output`, in this case, looks like this:

```
[{'key': 'a--b', 'code': '123', 'codes': array(['123', '098'], dtype='<U3')},
 {'key': 'c--d', 'code': '456', 'codes': array(['000', '999'], dtype='<U3')},
 {'key': 'e--f', 'code': '789', 'codes': array(['789', '432'], dtype='<U3')}]
```

I would like for that print statement to print a list. I understand I could simply do the following:

```
for row in output:
    row['codes'] = row['codes'].tolist()

# this now prints <class 'list'>, which is what I want
print(type(output[0]['codes']))
```

However, my dataframe is of course much more complicated than this, and I have multiple columns that are numpy arrays. I know I could expand the snippet above to check which columns are array type and cast them using `tolist()`, but I'm wondering if there is something snappier or more clever? Perhaps something provided by Pandas that is optimized?

To be clear, here is the output I need to have:

```
print(output)
[{'key': 'a--b', 'code': '123', 'codes': ['123', '098']},
 {'key': 'c--d', 'code': '456', 'codes': ['000', '999']},
 {'key': 'e--f', 'code': '789', 'codes': ['789', '432']}]
```

Comment: In regards to _**I know I could expand the snippet above to check which columns are array type**_ the dtype of a column containing `np.array` is object. If there are many columns, then you would probably need to check the type of the a single value in the column, assuming all values in the column are arrays. `cols = [col for col in df.columns if type(df.loc[0, col]) == np.ndarray]` and then `for col in cols: df[col] = df[col].map(np.ndarray.tolist)` will convert the arrays in each column to lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a list of the numpy-typed column names:

```
np_fields = ['codes']
```

and then I replaced each field in place in my dataframe:

```
for col in np_fields:
    data[col] = data[col].map(np.ndarray.tolist)
```

I then called `data.to_dict('records')` once that was complete.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first use `applymap` to convert numpy array's to python lists, then use `to_dict`

```
cols = ['codes']
data.assign(**data[cols].applymap(list)).to_dict('records')
```

---

```
[{'key': 'a--b', 'code': '123', 'codes': ['123', '098']},
 {'key': 'c--d', 'code': '456', 'codes': ['000', '999']},
 {'key': 'e--f', 'code': '789', 'codes': ['789', '432']}]
```

Comment: To be clear, this updates the output of `.to_dict` to have lists instead of arrays, but doesn't change the columns in `data`.